# Opening a PDF in an email

Tags: email, pdf

I received a PDF file in an email. I successfully opened it. Later, I went back to the email, but could not access the PDF again. The first time the PDF appeared as box. The second time I opened the email the PDF appears as follows: <2016 TIAHA Charity Golf Tournament, Participants 9-18-2016.xls>

How can I access the PDF a second time?

Answer (score 1):

.xls files are Microsoft Excel files, perhaps you might have opened it as a preview and it appeared as a pdf when in reality it is an excel file.

If it isn't the case, try restarting your mail client, sometimes the mail might have not loaded properly.

If it is neither of the above, provide a screenshot of how it is attached.